# Liferay 7 Themes and AUI

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I am having an issue with Liferay 7 Themes and AUI.  First, it is my understanding each Liferay page is divided into sections, as defined here:
- https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/setting-up-custom-css

And I must wrap any custom css with the appropriate wrapper, as defined in the above link.  Any css defined in the theme applies to the appropriate section of the page, for all pages in the web application.  I can also create custom wrappers within the theme, which individual portlets may reference using the 'com.liferay.portlet.css-class-wrapper' annotation.

I can therefore change the AUI Button's appearance by creating a css class and referring to it as follows:
`< aui:button cssClass="btn-lg".../>`

But it is less clear to me how I can apply custom css to AUI Data tables.  Guidance is certainly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [theme contributors](https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/theme-contributors).

And there create a .scss file and put customized styles for datatable there like :

```
.yui3-datatable{
  & thead{
    backgournd-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'your-theme/css/custom.csss' to override default style with your custom styles.